# Magento 2 different languages for website

Tags: magento2, locale

so I'm new to Magento and I'm making an online store for a client using Magento 2 CE.

Their company is based in Canada so they want to have a language selector for `English` and `French`.

I normally make websites in Wordpress, and have no idea where to start for Magento.. Would I need to make multiple stores, or what? Also how do I add the french translation content into the store?

Sorry if this is super simple, I'm trying to learn but don't want to learn the wrong way... if that makes any sense

Comment: You can also set up multi site switcher into front end like language switcher and store switcher .. refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290073/how-to-setup-magento-2-website-switcher

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To create 2 different languages for website, first you need to create other store view `(admin > Stores > All Stores > Create Store View)`

- Name: `French`

- Code: `fr`

- Status: `Enable`

Second, set default language for each store view `(Store > Configuration [General])`

For default store view, at `Locale Options` set Locate is `Englist (United States)`:

[image]

Save config

Change Store view to `French`

[image]

Uncheck `Use Website` and change `Locale` to `French (Canada)`

[image]

Save config. Done

Note: You can change `Default Store View` to `English`

Comment: i did the same but i can see the store switcher on frontend side in header links

Answer (score 1):

Yes as in magento 1.x you must create a new store for every new language so if your default store is in english you need to create a new one for french.

In the default theme "luma" you'll see the store name in the language selector.

Comment: You must clear cache and deploy static contents in order to see it (the same needed for any frontend change)