# Magento 2 different languages

Tags: magento2, language, locale

[Magento 2 different languages for website](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98291/magento-2-different-languages-for-website)

I did exactly everything according what the guy who posted the answer said.

Basically i set the default store to English then i created a new store view and here i set the language to dutch. Somehow everything is still in English.

Any idea how this comes?

Comment: Did you install the second language or just did the steps from the answer?

Comment: I didn't install any language i just followed the steps from the answer @Klettseb

Comment: What is the best way to do this? i need a dutch language pack.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you will have to install the language pack as well besides following the steps.

Language packs can be found for example [here](https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2).

I just copy and paste the installation instructions:

Download file corresponding to your language. 
It is a single file, that contains translations and module context. Easiest to download it to your installation root directory.

Now run the following command:

```
bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace -d source_[lang_code].csv langpack [lang_code]
```

where [lang_code] is language code like pl_PL.

As a result, a directory langpack will be created that contains proper structure of language files for your installation.

Copy it over to your Magento installation and the translations should be visible. If not, run the following commands to clear cache:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [lang_code]
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Note: additional directory i18n contains strings for which the module could not be found in your installation. This file can be skipped.

Another useful source [here](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5496-language-packs#w_installation)

Hope that helps you