# Magento 2 language is incorrect

Tags: language, magento-2.1.1

When I open my **.co.uk website**, it says a lot of stuff in Dutch from the pack I installed. I want my **German** website to be **German**, **Dutch** to be **Dutch** and **English** to be **English**.

> Why it is not working?
>
> How can I fix this?

I don't know from where to start.

**My website:**

> https://www.thefixedgearshop.co.uk

The storeviews:
[image: Storeviews]

Not switchable

[image: Locale not switchable]

Comment: it seems like Dutch and German have so many similarities. From where you got the language pack?

Comment: When I opened the site in chrome instead of German it is showing as Afrikaans. Please share the language pack details if possible.

Comment: The one language pack (NL) is imported from here:  https://github.com/ho-nl/magento2-nl_NL but the english and German one are not imported in their and come from the Magento Install. Can you inform me how we should proceed and why does English after the import of NL show NL language?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think the **package** that you have installed is a little **mixed**, try please to disable your translation modules and create three new by following and you can later customize them if necessary.

**Nb:** Regarding the translation files before adding them to the module, you have to check them first and make sure that they don't contain a mixture of languages.

Set well the right language for each store in admin panel.

> Here is the method for one module, do that for the other by changing
>   the code_ISO language !

1. `app/i18n/languageName/code_ISO/code_ISO.csv`

   **Exemple:** for the ***French*** language it will be like this: `app/i18n/french/fr_FR/fr_FR.csv`

   - You put your translation words inside `fr_FR.csv`like this :

   `"Hello","Bonjour"`

   - You can specify the translation for some module like this, *exemple* here is a **captcha module**
     `"Incorrect CAPTCHA","CAPTCHA incorrect",module,Magento_Captcha`
2. `app/i18n/languageName/code_ISO/language.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
       <code>code_ISO</code>
       <vendor>languageName</vendor>
       <package>code_iso</package>
   </language>
   ```

   French language **exemple**:
   `app/i18n/french/fr_FR/language.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
       <code>fr_FR</code>
       <vendor>french</vendor>
       <package>fr_fr</package>
   </language>
   ```
3. `app/i18n/languageName/code_ISO/registration.php`

   ```
   <?php
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
       'languageName_code_iso',
       __DIR__
   );
   ```

   French language **exemple**:
   `app/i18n/french/fr_FR/registration.php`

   ```
   <?php
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
       'french_fr_fr',
       __DIR__
       );
   ```
4. Clean your cache, deploy the static-content like this :

   - Delete the contents of `pub/static` except `.htaccess`
   - Delete the contents of `var/cache`
   - Delete the contents of `var/view_preprocessed`
   - Run this command:
     `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising and I will try asap. I noticed that the locale language on the website for english is set to Dutch (Netherlands, but I cannot edit this. The uncheck box for Use Website is not clickable. How do I solve this? That could be the reason it's dutch right?

Comment: I you want to have different languages for one website, you have to create other storeview and you set the right language for each store view. however if you want to have different languages for different websites, you just have to create one store and one storeview then you the right language for each. for more information : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98307/48355

Comment: I have this set-up already. See the new picture in the first question. I am switching to this storeview (english for instance, but cannot switch (photo edit 2) to this locale.

Comment: Even if you uncheck the checkbox it doesnt work ?

Comment: I cannot uncheck the box, it's grayed out.

Comment: I don't know why !. It should not be greyed out. it may be that you have some  errors in admin. Ather idea : change the values ​​of thèse website in database. Do a backup before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74077/discussion-between-axel-dekker-and-prince).

Comment: I cannot figure out where to change this for English to en_US, Netherlands to nl_NL and Germany to de_DE in the db.